# Is there any arithmetic formula that can test all given numbers are in row, like [ 3 5 4 ]

Tags: dart

I m making a card game where 3 random numbers are generated..I need to check are these numbers  Row numbers...

like 4 6 5  and  23,24,22. are row numbers

I have made method but I think there should be easy arithmetic formulas

I have tried this and working well, but I need simple arithmatic formula to avoid use of array and for

```
bool isAllInRow(int num1, int num2,int num3)
{
  //subject : tinpati
  List<int> numbers=[num1,num2,num3];
  bool is_in_row=true;
  numbers.sort();

  if(numbers[0]==1 && numbers[1]==12 && numbers[2]==13)
    return true;

  for(int x=0;x<numbers.length-1;x++)
    {
      if(numbers[x]-numbers[x+1]!=-1)
        {
          is_in_row=false;
          break;
        }
    }
  return is_in_row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know if the cards form a straight, with aces both low and high.

Is the "three cards" fixed, or would you want to generalize to more cards?

Sorting should be cheap for such a short list, so that's definitely a good start. Then you just need to check the resulting sequence is increasing adjacent values.

I'd do it as:

```dart
bool isStraight(List<int> cards) {
  var n = cards.length;
  if (n < 2) return true;
  cards.sort();
  var first = cards.first;
  if (first == 1 && cards[1] != 2) {
    // Pretend Ace is Jack if n == 3.
    // Accepts if remaining cards form a straight up to the King.
    first = 14 - n;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (cards[i] != first + i) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This code rejects card sets that have duplicates, or do not form a straight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Arithmetic Progression.

```
bool checkForAP(List<int> numberArr) {
    numberArr.sort();
    int diff = numberArr[1] - numberArr[0];
    if (numberArr[2] - numberArr[1] != diff) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

And modify your function like

```
bool isAllInRow(int num1, int num2,int num3) {
  //subject : tinpati
  List<int> numbers=[num1,num2,num3];
  bool is_in_row=true;
  numbers.sort();

  if(numbers[0]==1 && numbers[1]==12 && numbers[2]==13)
    return true;

  return checkForAP(numbers);
}
```

> Note: remove sort in AP method as it is of no use. Since your numbers
> list length is 3 I directly compared numbers for AP, the same can also
> be written for n numbers with for.

```
bool checkForAp(numberArr) {
    numberArr.sort();
    int diff = numberArr[1] - numberArr[0];
    for(int i = 2; i< numberArr.length ;i++) {
      if (numberArr[i] - numberArr[i - 1] != diff) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
bool isAllInRow(int num1, int num2,int num3) {
  if (num1 == num2 || num2 == num3) return false;
  var maxNum = max(num1, max(num2, num3));
  var minNum = min(num1, min(num2, num3));
  return (maxNum - minNum == 2) || (minNum == 1 && maxNum == 13 && num1 + num2 + num3 == 26);
}
```